# Can we recover $|X(k)|$, given $|x(n)|$?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, dft, magnitude

Given a complex vector $x[n]$, we can find the magnitudes of the spectrum by computing:

$X_m[k] = |X[k]| = |FFT[x]|$

This involves performing a complex FFT and computing the absolute value of the result. There is consideration to take advantage of a real FFT for hardware simplifications, by computing the magnitude of the input time domain vector $x[n]$ and using the spectrum of that to derive the traditional full calculation.

If given a real vector $y[n]$ which holds magnitudes of the original complex vector $ y[n] = |x[n]|$, is it possible to recover the magnitude of the spectrum $X_m[k]$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{FFT}(A) &= \text{FFT}([1, -1, 1, -1]) = [0, 0, 4, 0]\\
\text{FFT}(B) &= \text{FFT}([1, 1, 1, 1])  = [4, 0, 0, 0]
\end{align}
$$

so $|A| = |B|$ while $|\text{FFT}(A)| \neq |\text{FFT}(B)|$. The most we can recover is the square sum:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |x[n]|^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} |X[k]|^2
$$

Put simply, modulus loses too much information. Yes, we want $|X|$, which also has less information, but to get $|X|$, we must first get $X$, which we cannot do from $|x|$.